# Do Mahabharata or any other scripture says that Bhishma is a Jivan Muktha?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, moksha, bhishma

[Bhishma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhishma) is a well-known person from Mahabharata. He is a grand father of both Kauravas and Pandavas. Almost everyone respect him.

Consider the following slokha from Mahabharata and its translation

> **अयं बरह्मविदां शरेष्ठॊ अयं बरह्मविदां गतिः**
>
> इत्य अभाषन्त भूतानि शयानं भरतर्षभम
>
> [[12, 115, 6, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs06115.htm)

Translation

> **This one is the foremost of those conversant with the Vedas! This one
> is the best of those that are conversant with the Vedas!**--Even thus
> did creatures speak of that bull among men as he lay (on his bed of
> arrows).
>
> [[Section 121, Bhagavat-Gita Parva, Bhishma Parva, The Mahabharata
> ]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06121.htm)

Here the word **बरह्मविदां** has been translated as  **conversant with the Vedas!**, which may be true and are there any other possible interpretations for the same word as **liberated or Brahman (Jivan Muktha)**?

Along with it, are there any other slokha from Mahabharata or other scriptures say that Bhishma is a Jivan Muktha to support it?

Comment: Jivanmukta is a big thing. His knowledge is infinite. Bhisma on the other hand said that he was unable to speak even the Shiva Sahasranama when asked to do so (by Yudhhisthira I think). Eventually Sri Krishna had to reveal the Sahasranama (My knowledge of Mahabharata is worst so I might be wrong in the details). So Bhisma was not by any means.

Comment: @Rickross but many times in scriptures, jivanmuktas does not behave like sarvagnas... Don't know in detail. But just opining.

Comment: May be but IMO Jivanmuktas mostly behave like retarded or mad persons if they live in a society. Mostly they won't live among humans.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Jivan mukta is, but the translation probably is alluding to the fact that bhishma knew the mantras for the activation of astras among other vedic intricacies

Comment: Jivan Mukta means a living liberated person.

Comment: I don't think so, those would be Krishna, vyasa, etc but it's best to read about bhishma in the epic itself if you want to know more about him.